# Gradle build failing downloading dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I am having spring boot gradle project...but its not able download the first dependencies (oa-common.3.0.0.jar) It looks like its not going to artifactory to fetch it..even though its mentioned in the repositories....what I am doing wrong..any suggestion?

build.gradle file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        credentials {
            username "${artifactory_user}"
            password "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}

wrapper {
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.BIN
}

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation('com.ge.digital.oa.common:oa-common:3.0.0') { 
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude group: 'io.micrometer', module: 'micrometer-core'
    }
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
```

We have the artifacory jar
My Artifactory path:

```
ARJLY
 com/ge
  digital/oa
   common
     oa-common
      3.0.0
       oa-common-3.0.0.jar
```

Error:

```
$ gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies
> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.ge.digital.oa.common:oa-common:3.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 18s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Comment: 1. try to clean com.ge.digital.oa.common in ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1 
2. Ensure you are able to download artifact from the browser
3. remove mavenLocal() as a repository if this project has no dependency with other project artifact
4. check pom published in location and jars in different 

`repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://repo2.mycompany.com/maven2"
        artifactUrls "http://repo.mycompany.com/jars"
    }
}`

Comment: I am able to download from browser...I commented mavenlocal() but still same error..I even commented maven{..} itself. its still the same error..looks like its not even going to artifactory to bring the jar...how do I force gradle to go to artifactory to pull the jar?

Comment: two way we can achieve 1.  --refresh-dependencies 2. tell gradle not to cache `configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}` and 
`dependencies {
    compile('com.ge.digital.oa.common:oa-common:3.0.0'){
        changing=true
    }
}`

Comment: added both...but still same error

Comment: run `gradle --stacktrace` and view the full stack trace. Hope you checked jar is downloading via browser / curl / wget

Comment: if Gradle behind a corporate proxy network ? add this  `systemProp.http.proxyHost=xx.xx.xx.xxx
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8888
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|xx.xx.xx.*
systemProp.https.proxyHost=xx.xx.xx.xxx
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8888
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|xx.xx.xx.*` in gradle.properties

Comment: even after adding proxy ..same error..here is the gardle build --scan report https://gradle.com/s/63cvtrwi7ufj2

Comment: Check the [oa-common.pom](https://artifactory.build.ge.com/ARJLY/com/ge/digital/oa/common/oa-common/3.0.0/oa-common-3.0.0.pom) and verify oa-common.jar properly uploaded